How can I force calculation of Tkinter Text height when it contains windows?
I'm creating an editor application that uses tkinter Text to open files which contain a mix of data to be displayed as text and data to be displayed by a couple of different widgets. Textual data is inserted using the .insert() method while widgets are created and then displayed using .create_window().
I'm using .see() to provide 'goto' functionality i.e. jumping to a given position in the text. When a file is first opened, this does not work correctly - the scroll bar jumps too far and the desired line of text is off-screen. However, if I manually scroll through the whole file first, the goto function works fine. During the scroll, you can see the size of the scroll control changing as the widgets appear.
The culprit seems to be a miscalculation of the total height of the Text widget in relation to the widgets displayed within it. For example, calling .count('1.0', 'end', 'ypixels') on a particular file immediately after it has been opened gives a value of ~20,000px. Calling .count('1.0', 'end', 'update') and then getting 'ypixels' again gives a value of ~15,000px. In both cases, the .see method does not work correctly. Having scrolled to the end of the document, 'ypixels' then returns ~10,000px which I suppose is the true value.
Aside from trying .count -update, I have also tried update_idletasks() but am unable to programmatically get the application to calculate the correct value for ypixels (which I'm assuming is the cause of the original .see issue).
How get I get tkinter to compute the correct ypixel value when the Text widget is initialised?

The Text widget has a property called wrap, what value have you given it?

It is better to provide a [mre] in order to identify the issue.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
